# user-select:none breaking Safari contenteditable

Tags: css, html, safari, contenteditable

I have a div with `contenteditable="true"`. I can enter text into the `div` with IE, Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. I finally tracked the problem down to the style declarations below given to the container of the div.

```
container {
    -webkit-user-select : none;
    -moz-user-select    : none;
    -khtml-user-select  : none;
    -ms-user-select     : none;  
}
```

I put these in a while ago per [Chrome taking first double-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331795/chrome-taking-first-double-click) to keep the container from turning blue when it was double-clicked.  Now I'm just finding out that that solution breaks Safari `contenteditable`.

Does anyone know exactly what these things are doing and why they break Safari `contenteditable`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### `user-select`

This property controls the actual [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Selection) operation<sup>0</sup>. This is useful in situations where you want to provide an easier/cleaner copy-paste experience for users (not have them accidentally text-select useless things, like icons or images).<sup>1</sup>

Example of how the property works: http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/vGG8F/3/

### Possible Solutions

Since Safari is built on webkit `-webkit-user-select : none;` is the culprit. Removing that will allow the `contenteditable` to work again. However, you need that due to your original problem.

1. Others have run into the same problem which may provide a solution.

   - [contenteditable div not actually editable in webkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251227/contenteditable-div-not-actually-editable-in-webkit)
   - [Losing selected text from contenteditable on clicking div with css user-select: none;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197580/losing-selected-text-from-contenteditable-on-clicking-div-with-css-user-select)
   - [ContentEditable focus in Chrome/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904149/contenteditable-focus-in-chrome-safari)
2. You could also [catch the double click as suggested in your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20331943/1085891) and then disable the `-webkit-user-select` allowing the `div` to be editable. Once the editing is complete `-webkit-user-select` could be set back to `none`.

<sup>0</sup> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select
<sup>1</sup> http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/u/user-select/

Comment: Wow!  You nailed it!  How can I just send all my questions to you? :)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure you got the 50 points ok.  My points seemed to pop back up awfully quick and it's possible I didn't click something I should have to give you the points. (All I did was click the check mark for your answer.)

Answer (score 2):

[Use](http://jsfiddle.net/JjXrz/) CSS pseudo-element `::selection`. Chrome, for example, [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aselection) it from version 1.

Comment: Tested in Safari on Mac, blue highlight is transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Let me add a bit to JSuar's answer. Not only `-webkit-user-select: none;` kills the contenteditables, but `-khtml-user-select: none;` also does. 
However, setting explicit `-webkit-user-select: text;` or `-webkit-user-select: auto;` does the job disabling both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me.

```css
*[contenteditable]:empty {
    caret-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Then either animate the left border flashing or simply style the input in a way which indicates focus.